# why is child process running code meant for parent

Tags: c, fork

The snippet below is being run by the child process as well but I don't know why because to my understanding the child's Pid should always be 0 so there's no reason for it to ever do anything below but print "I am child";

```
 pid_t child_Pid1 = fork();

 if((int)getpid() == 0) {
 printf("I am child\n");
 } else {
    printf("I am parent\n");
    }
```

Comment: The child only exists when `fork()` returns. It "returns" in two processes, parent and child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getpid()` always returns the current process's pid which is never zero, so in your current code, neither of the two processes does the `execlp`.

You want to look at `child_Pid1` instead of `getpid()`.  In the child it returns 0 **instead of** the child's pid.

Comment: Also ```child_Pid1``` should be checked to see if ```fork()``` failed.